# Store all php script output to file transparently

Tags: php, apache, logging

I am trying to develop very simple PHP application which is logging whole HTTP input and output to file transparently.

I am using `auto_prepend_file` directive to run my app and I am also using `register_shutdown_function()` inside of it to catch the moment when analyzed script has been finished.

A problem I have is to catch whole script output. I think I can't to use `ob_start()` or `ob_get_clean()` because I don't know if analyzed script using direct output or not. Actually I don't know what analyzed script going to do, because I am going to log any request and any answer and I don't want to affect analyzed site even a bit.

How do I catch **any** PHP script output transparently without affecting its functionality?

Comment: Added code highlighting and made the question a little more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Would you be willing to consider options that don't run from the PHP side?  `tcpdump` and `tcpflow` can both dump TCP traffic like you're describing here.  I'm not sure if that would work for you, but dumping the entire request and response from each request in PHP doesn't seem like a very good production solution, so it kind of makes me think you're going for debugging insights, so tcpdump may do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) without developing a php application.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all, I've tried to use `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()` and this couple works great. No functionality was lost in monitoring app (however it is quite huge app).